# VBA to Select Each Option in a Drop List

Tags: excel, vba

Update to code & question:
The current code in the module for this sheet is as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B2")) Is Nothing Then
          Application.Run "MonthlyRead"
     End If
End Sub

Sub MPrintAll()
     Dim c As String
     Dim MonthlyList As Range
     Set MonthlyList = Worksheets("Monthly").Range("MonthlyList").Cells
     For Each cell In MonthlyList
         Range("b2").Value = cell.Value
         ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Monthly").PrintOut
     Next cell
End Sub
```

I've been stepping through the code, to try to identify where the problems occur. When I press F8 after "Range("b2").Value = cell.Value" it immediately goes to the first line of code for the sheet, completely skipping the Print command. Also, it deletes the first value in the named range, instead of copy-pasting it to cell B2.

For reference, here's the code in Module1 called by the first routine above:

```
    Sub MonthlyRead()
         Call MEFTPS
         Call MUCT6
    End Sub
    Sub MEFTPS()
         If Range("a2").Value = "EFTPS Package" Then
              Call MShow
              Else: Call MHide
         End If
    End Sub
    Sub MHide()
        Rows("20:20").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("31:31").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("42:42").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("53:53").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Range("B2").Select
    End Sub
    Sub MShow()
        Rows("20:20").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("31:31").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("42:42").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("53:53").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Range("B2").Select
    End Sub
    Sub MUCT6()
        If Range("g3").Value = "Y" Then
             Call UCT6MShow
             Else: Call UCT6MHide
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub UCT6MHide()
        Rows("19:19").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("30:30").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("41:41").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("52:52").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Range("B2").Select
    End Sub
    Sub UCT6MShow()
        Rows("19:19").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("30:30").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("41:41").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("52:52").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Range("B2").Select
    End Sub
```

---

I'm working with a dynamic worksheet that populates an individualized payment schedule, based on a selection from a data validation drop-list at the top of the page. There are approximately 300 options in the drop-list. These schedules are then printed, to verify information obtained from 2 other programs, all of which must be printed, copied, scanned, packed, and mailed in a single day.

I'm looking for VBA code that can select each client name from the drop-list in order, from the beginning to the end of the list. The list is populated from a named range on another sheet, named "QtrlyList."

I have some very simple code, that doesn't work.

```
    Sub PrintAll()
        For Each cell In QtrlyList
            Worksheets("Normal").PrintOut
        Next cell
    End Sub
```

Whenever I try to run the code, I get a "Type Mismatch" error. I'm fairly certain this is coming from "cell" or "QtrlyList." I'm just not sure how to fix it.

Comment: What kind of drop-down is it?

Comment: It's a data validation drop-down, populated from a named range.

Comment: Is that all your code? If you are going through cells in named range I believe you need `Range("QtrlyList")` for starters.

Comment: I'm a novice with VBA. I can usually use google-fu to find snippets of code to cobble together, but not this time. When I change "In QtrlyList" to "In Range("QtrlyList"), I get error 400. If I step through the code, I get "Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" on the second line of code.

Comment: I've gotten it somewhat functional. Now, the problem seems to be getting the selection to display in cell B2, before the VBA sends the Print command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work for you (untested)

```
Sub PrintAll()

    Dim wb as Workbook, cell as Range

    Set Wb = ActiveWorkbook 'or ThisWorkBook if the code is in your reporting workbook 

    For Each cell In wb.Sheets("SheetNameHere").Range("QtrlyList").Cells
        With wb.Worksheets("Normal")
            'you want to set the value of whichever cell has the drop-down
           .Range("D2")).value=cell.Value
           DoEvents 'allow sheet to pick up changed value
           .PrintOut
        End with
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Both this code and what I've managed to figure out with the help of Google, Stackoverflow, & one of my co-workers have the same issue. They reach the line of code for inputting the value into cell B2 (drop-down list location) & immediately go back to the first line of code. Even when stepping through using F8, I get to that line, & I'm back at the beginning of the code, without ever touching the print command.

Comment: This is the code I currently have. `Sub MPrintAll()
    Dim c As String
    Dim MonthlyList As Range
    Set MonthlyList = Worksheets("Monthly").Range("MonthlyList").Cells
    For Each cell In MonthlyList
        Worksheets("Monthly").Range("b2") = c
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Monthly").PrintOut
    Next cell
End Sub`

Comment: Look at the code module for the sheet with the drop-down.  Is there some code these?

Comment: The module for the sheet has the code I just posted & a Private Sub to hide/unhide certain rows if A2 has text in it. Also, I just noticed that when I step through using F8, the first value in the list is deleted, instead of pasting into cell B2.

Comment: Can you post the other code?  And - update your question: code in comments is hard to follow.

Comment: Are you sure the first value is getting deleted, and not just hidden with one of the rows when `MonthlyRead` runs?  And can you post this workbook somewhere? - this question is running a bit long...

Comment: Unfortunately, the file includes a lot of confidential information. I can't post it. The list is below that printed portion of the page. It's not being hidden. After I run the sub, the cell is just empty.

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted which sets or clears any cell values, other than B2, so I have no idea how the first value in the list could be getting cleared.

Comment: When I came in to work this morning, I tried running the sub from the button on the sheet. It worked perfectly. Now, I'm going to try transferring the code over to the other schedule, that has 200+ clients, instead of 7.